# Crop raster data surrounded by NoData

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, clip

I have a fairly large geotiff that has only a small area of interest. I have used clip by rectangle to generate a new geotiff of this area of interest but the resulting geotiff is the same size as the original raster (in both size and extent), with the area of interest present but surrounded by nodata.

Is there way to essentially crop the rectangle of real data out from the nodata?

Comment: Thanks all for your help - in the end, it was far faster to just redo the operation with a rough polygon and the Extract by Mask tool then it was to generate a mask of the nodata areas (I gave up on this process at around the 2 hour mark). For the record, ArcGIS 10.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *Extract By Mask* tool available in the Spatial Analyst tools.  Make sure you do not have a geoprocessing setting set to save raster outputs to the same extent as the the input raster.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a 'clip by rectangle' so i'm assuming you are using  'extract by rectangle' which will turn cells outside of the rectangle to nodata, leaving the output raster with the same extents as the input raster.

Try using the actual clip function in the raster processing toolset and you should be fine.

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/clip.htm

Note: I used the latest documentation from ESRI because I do not know what version you are using, but this tool has been out for sometime and should be relevant so long as you are using a relatively recent version of ArcGIS.